# Can't get past ImportError [Odoo 9.0]

Tags: odoo, importerror, parse-error, traceback, odoo-9

I'm just running through the "Building a Module" documentation for v9 and am following along.

My code looks identical to the examples here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html.

When I start the server this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

execute(self.server.app)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute

application_iter = app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/server.py", line 245, in app

return self.app(e, s)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application

return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied

result = handler(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1488, in __call__

return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1462, in __call__

return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__

return self.app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1637, in dispatch

ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 360, in registry

return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 354, in get

update_module)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 385, in new

openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 334, in load_modules

force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules

loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 123, in load_module_graph

load_openerp_module(package.name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/module.py", line 324, in load_openerp_module

__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/module.py", line 61, in load_module

mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)

File "/home/lslaz/odoo-dev/addons/openacademy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

from . import models

ImportError: cannot import name models

^C2016-02-03 19:54:08,626 3329 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating shutdown

2016-02-03 19:54:08,626 3329 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
```

If I delete the "from . import models" from the init.py I get a different error:

```
ParseError: "Invalid model name in the action definition.
None" while parsing /home/lslaz/odoo-dev/addons/openacademy/views/views.xml:8, near

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
    <field name="name">Courses</field>
    <field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Create the first course
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Please help! I'm confident that both there things are as they should be but I can't move forward until I figure out what the problem is.

Comment: where is stored model `openacademy.course`? can you print path to your model?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Openacademy/__init__.py & __openerp__.py also has controllers/, demo/, models/, security/, and views/. I used the odoo.py scaffold command so the file structure and files were all provided for me.

Comment: First what you need is check that file with models is exists here: 
`path_to_your_addons/openacademy/models.py`

Comment: models it is folder in your module? or just .py file?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar it's openacademy/models/models.py. So __init__.py is not a sibling.

Comment: Update: WOW! Didn't even think to move it since it was auto generated, but that worked! Any idea on the ParseError?

Comment: Thanks for reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but in my case Odoo generates models like *.py* file in new application, but not like folder.

If you want use folder for your models you need:

1) import models in your `__init__.py` like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import models
```

2) create `__init__.py` in folder *models* and import your all models like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import my_model_one
import one_more_model
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is slightly late but I am also following the tutorial and here is how I solved this problem:

When creating the wizard.py file, the tutorial doesn't show the imports that are necessary. But you have to import the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import fields, models, api

class Wizard(models.TransientModel): ...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `.` from the line `from . import models` so that it reads `from import models`.